# Generate a randomly-oriented vector $\vec{w}$ at a specific angle $\theta$ from another vector $\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vectors, rotations, sampling

I'm currently facing a problem where I need to perturb a provided vector $\vec{v}$ to produce a new vector $\vec{w}$, where both are located in $\mathbb{R}^n$, by perturbing both the magnitude and orientation of $\vec{v}$. The first part of this perturbation is straightforward, as I will only need to perturb the magnitude of $\vec{v}$ such that
$$
m = \frac{\lVert\vec{w}\rVert}{\lVert\vec{v}\rVert} \sim Q,
$$
where $Q$ is some specified probability distribution that can be sampled from. Put short, the result of this perturbation will just be a scalar multiplication of the original vector $\vec{v}$ (i.e. $\lVert \vec{w} \rVert = \lVert m \vec{v}\rVert$).

The second part of this perturbation is much harder. At the end of the perturbation, the new vector $\vec{w}$ must be oriented such that it is located at a specific angle $\theta$ away from $\vec{v}$,
$$
\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}}{\lVert\vec{v}\rVert\lVert\vec{w}\rVert}\right) \sim U,
$$
where $U$ is another specified probability distribution. With the exception of this constraint, the new vector $\vec{w}$ should be randomly oriented.

Whether or not this is useful, another way of thinking of this problem is that the new vector $\vec{w}$ must lie on the surface of the $n$-cone that is an angle $\theta$ away from $\vec{v}$, with the constraint such that it have a magnitude $m\lVert v \rVert$. These two constraints should limit the possible vectors to a $(n-2)$-dimensional surface (i.e. in $\mathbb{R}^3$, this amounts to choosing a random position on a circle).

What is the best way to go about this? I have found previous solutions for producing a random orientation in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I can't come up with a way to also implement these constraints.

Comment: My idea would be (in $\mathbb{R}^3$): All the vectors of length $m$ that have angle $\theta$ with $\vec{v}$ (and point in the same direction) lie on a single circle in a plane that is perpendicular to $\vec{v}$. Therefore drawing another angle in $[0,2\pi]$ from the uniform distribution would uniquely determine a vector with the given properties. Im not sure if this can be generalized to higher dimensions.

Comment: I think the same thing as in my previous comment can be done in any dimension using $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about this a bit more it's definitely going to have something to do with sampling points from an $(n-2)$-sphere, which like you mentioned will be equivalent to sampling from $\left[0, 2\pi\right]$ in $n=3$

Comment: I edited my answer since there was a big mistake in it.

Answer (score 1):

As i wrote in the comments, the problem can be solved by using spherical coordinates.

Without restriction of generality let $\vec{v} = (1, \dots ,0)$.

We can describe any point $x = (x_1, \dots , x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ by its unique spherical coordinates $(r,\varphi_1 ,s)  \in (0,\infty) \times [0,\pi] \times \mathbb{S}^{n-2}$, where $\mathbb{S}^{n-2}$ is the $n-2$ dimensional sphere (assuming $n>2$). With the relation between them given by

\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos(\varphi_1)  \\
x_2 &= r \sin(\varphi_1) s_1 \\
x_3 &= r \sin (\varphi_1)s_2 \\
&\vdots \\
x_n &= r \sin  (\varphi_1) s_{n-2},
\end{align}
where $s= (s_1, \dots , s_{n-2})$.

The angle between $\vec{v}$ and $x$ is $\varphi_1$ and $\|x\| =r$.

Your problem is therefore solved by the following procedure:

- Draw $r$ and $\varphi_1$ according to their specific distributions
- Draw a sample from the uniform distribution on the $n-2$ sphere
- Compute the output vector in cartesian coordinates using the above formula

### Edit

I just realized that there was a big mistake in my answer. The uniform distribution in the angular variables and then using the coordinate transform will not yield the uniform distribution on the $n-2$ sphere.

Instead we can sample from the uniform distribution on the $n-2$ sphere using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_on_the_(n_%E2%88%92_1)-sphere). I have changed the above procedure so that it actually works.